# How would a phrase such as "Does the pope sh*t in the woods" be classified? The closest I can get is "intentional malapropism".

Tags: slang, malapropisms

How would phrases such as "Does the pope sh*t in the woods? Does a bear wear a funny hat?" be classified? The closest I can get is "intentional malapropism". Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would classify it as sacredly geographic and arboreal.

Comment: I prefer "Are bears Catholic?"

Answer (score 10):

This is known as a [mixed metaphor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixed%20metaphor):

> **Mixed metaphor**: a figure of speech combining inconsistent or incongruous metaphor

The specific phrase "*Does the Pope shit in the woods?*" (quoting *The Big Lebowski*) is listed on [TV Trope's page dedicated to mixed metaphors](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MixedMetaphor), and is [cited over at the Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-12982.html) message boards as well.

For fun, here's [a long list of mixed metaphors](http://www.jimcarlton.com/my_favorite_mixed_metaphors.htm).

Comment: FWIW, with all deference to The Dude, that phrase predates both the film and The Dude ([the real one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Dowd)).

Comment: This is a very complicated case, @Drew. You know, a lotta ins, lotta outs, lotta what-have-you's.

Comment: I can't see anything metaphorical about the two questions that are combined here.

Comment: @Edwin, please see "[Rhetorical questions as metaphors](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question#Rhetorical_questions_as_metaphors)" on Wikipedia, which explains the relationship and gives both "Does a bear shit in the woods?" and "Is the Pope Catholic?" as specific examples.

Comment: That's really stretching the classical definition of 'metaphor'. I can't find support for Wikipedia's analysis / terminology; I'd probably veer towards simile here (Earth is round as surely as Pope is Catholic).

Comment: @edwin So sorry, such Shelleyan syntactic synthesis surely should've suggested, synonymously, "*simile salad*".

Comment: Sounds almost as bad as a Diet of Worms.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, the two defining characteristics of phrases like the ones you mentioned are as follows.

- They are *rhetorical affirmations*; the answer to the question is understood to be obviously "yes".
- They are *intentional malapropisms*; you are mixing and matching portions of different rhetorical affirmations.

Therefore, they could be classified as *intentionally malaproposed rhetorical affirmations*.

Comment: To be contrary, try using *rhetorical negations*, like "Does a duck-billed platypus have a bellybutton?"